# How to show button on image onhover

Tags: html, css

I am trying to show a button element on top of an image when the user hovers over it.

My desired result is something like this:

[image]

This is the code I have so far:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6" style="background-image:url(https://i.imgur.com/fZ3S5qJ.jpg);background-size: 100% 100%;height: 400px;"></div>  
    <div class="col-md-6" style="background-image:url(https://i.imgur.com/jTFqukV.jpg);background-size: 100% 100%;height: 400px;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Alicia I don't have an idea how to do this..

Comment: <div class="button"><a href="#"> BUTTON </a></div> to add a button to your html and then you would have to style it using CSS. Such as .container:hover .button {
  opacity: 1;
}
There are plenty of resources on the internet for this question. Try https://codepen.io/philcheng/pen/YWyYwG

Comment: Have you researched this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something [like this](https://codepen.io/icaromh/pen/rbgrxP):

```css
a {
  display: none;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn-like {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #FFF;
  padding: 5px;
  color: #FFF;
}

.col-md-6:hover a{
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6" style="background-image:url(https://i.imgur.com/fZ3S5qJ.jpg);background-size: 100% 100%;height: 400px;">
          <a href="https://google.com"><span class="btn-like">Buy now</span></a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6" style="background-image:url(https://i.imgur.com/jTFqukV.jpg);background-size: 100% 100%;height: 400px;">
          <a href="https://google.com"><span class="btn-like">Buy now</span></a>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I want this. But when I put this code in my it doesn't work. It only shows the "buy now" button..

Comment: Are you using the `bootstrap` right? You might add a class to the `a` element to avoid overwrite the properties set by bootstrap. And you probably it's a good idea not add the style into the same element of `col-md-6`, because it already has a lot of things inherited from bootstrap.

Comment: yes i'm using bootstrap 4.3.1 and the CSS code is in another file "style.css"

Comment: @Mitko so, as I'd said it's probably a good idea to move your image to another element. Like in this example: https://codepen.io/icaromh/pen/rbgrxP  

The main idea here it's to hide the button by default (`.image-wrapper a` at this line). And shows on hover as this line: `.image-wrapper:hover a`

Comment: It's not working again... When I reload page picture look like this https://i.imgur.com/EaCZGCv.png Are you using bootstrap 4.3.1 version?

Comment: @Mitko Maybe some styles are applying for your links (`a` element) that prevents to hide them. If you inspect them in your DevTools it will show what's the rule applied for them. 

You can add the `!important` modifier to the `display: none` and `display: flex;` (like: `display: flex !important;` and them will (probably) work. Besides, are you using `a` tags or `button` tag?

Comment: I'm using a tag. I just copy your code instead of my code. In DevTools I don't see this CSS code for elements..